# Web Socket security in Spring cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have setup the gateway with a 2 load balanced Web socket servers.

```java
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        //@formatter:off
        return builder.routes()
                .route("ws", r -> r.path("/ws/**")
                        .uri("lb://chat-service"))
                .build();
        //@formatter:on
}
```

The application is secured by JWt server.

```java
 @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }
```

Can we authenticate the Web socket hand shake witch is a HTTP upgrade request.
So the request be like,

ws://localhost:8080/ws/echo?token=xxxx

As I have seen the **GatewayFilter** will be what I will need but I did not quite get the picture how to do it.
Any alternative way would be helpful.
thanks.

Spring boot version  : 2.1.4.RELEASE
spring cloud version : Greenwich.RELEASE

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-gateway-oauth2login/?

Comment: Hi @spencergibb, Yes I have tried it by adding a web socket at resource server. It gives WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws/echo?token=xxxx' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302. I think the gateway is redirecting to UAA server. Earlier days we can just add ?access_token=xxxx to the URL and it authorized. Is that functionality removed some how? Or am I doing it wrong?